# Was a table created with iq unique option?

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I have some tables on **sybase-iq** data base, created for example:

```
create  table tab
(   
   id   int  not null IQ Unique (10)
)
```

How can I check if table `tab` was created with `iq unique` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that using procedure `sp_column`. It returns informations about every column in the table. In a `est_cardinality` column is the value from `IQ Unique`. For example:

```
sp_iqcolumn tab
```

returns

```
table_name  table_owner column_name domain_name width   scale   nulls   default cardinality est_cardinality location    isPartitioned   remarks check
tab         DBA         id          integer     4       0       N               0           10               Main       N
```

[Here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?workingSet=All%20topics&searchWord=sp_iqcolumn) is link to documentation.